# Unregister interpolated animated value

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, react-native-animatable

Is there a way to unbind an interpolated value and animate it on its own?

```
this.dragX = this.translateX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 75],
      outputRange: [0, 75],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
```

In some function, I want to animate the dragX value on its own without listening to translateX

```
Animated.timing(this.dragX, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 150,
      easing: Easing.easeIn,
      useNativeDriver,
}
```

Is that possible? Or are there other workarounds?